# logstash and monolog formatter

Tags: logging, logstash, monolog

I am using the monolog logstashFormater to create my logs, than I want to insert it in to my logstash.

Here is an example of a log created by monolog:

```
{"@timestamp":"2014-12-08T09:07:54.810335+00:00","@source":"devServer","@fields":{"channel":"orderLogger","level":100,"ctxt_site":"roulette","ctxt_country":"uk","ctxt_type":"virtual"},"@message":"order","@tags":["orderLogger"],"@type":"core"}
```

It is built good for logstash,
now I load the logstash with this config

```
input {
   stdin { }
}

output {
   stdout { codec => rubydebug }
}
```

but now I try to paste the created log from monolog and I get this:

```
{
   "message" => "{\"@timestamp\":\"2014-12-08T09:07:54.810335+00:00\",\"@source\":\"devServer\",\"@fields\":{\"channel\":\"orderLogger\",\"level\":100,\"ctxt_site\":\"roulette\",\"ctxt_country\":\"uk\",\"ctxt_type\":\"virtual\"},\"@message\":\"order\",\"@tags\":[\"orderLogger\"],\"@type\":\"core\"}",
  "@version" => "1",
"@timestamp" => "2014-12-08T09:08:24.800Z",
      "host" => "logstash"
}
```

so as you can see, logstash didn't parse it right, it simply place all the string inside the message.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The logs come as JSON messages so you'll want to use the correct codec for this:

```
input {
  stdin {
    codec => json
  }
}
```

Unrelated to this, note that monolog apparently produces log messages that fits old versions of Logstash where the 'message' field was named '@message' and so on. You should either run a more recent monolog or rename the fields afterwards using the [mutate filter](http://logstash.net/docs/1.4.2/filters/mutate).

Comment: In case anyone stumbles onto this today: [monolog uses V1 format by default now](https://github.com/Seldaek/monolog/blob/master/src/Monolog/Formatter/LogstashFormatter.php)